# Looking for a fast library to render PDF's files with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Does anyone knows about a fast library to render PDF's files with PHP?

I'm trying with dompdf but it's really slow, it takes about 5 minutes to render a PDF of 23 sheets.

Dompdf is amazing and really useful, but when you've to render large pdf's files is worthless.

I'm using dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3.

Has anyone experimented with larges pdfs in php using another library?

Could I improve this with dompdf? Here is the html file which dompdf renders:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15451865/pdf.html

I'm thinking about to write a service with openoffice library but I don't like to use another technology only for this.

Comment: personally, i would just start downloading regular old executable software to create the pdfs, and just have php pass args/data to it via exec()

Comment: dompdf does have some performance issues rendering tables. You're currently using nested tables, which will cause a hit on performance. I don't see any reason you need to use nested tables in the sample, though, so you could speed things up by simplifying your table structure.

Comment: You could also try using PDFLib as the back end. It does help improve performance. Though the licensing cost may be prohibitive, depending on your project.

Comment: FYI, you can see a sample simplified structure here: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug_tests/so11416920.htm (though rendering is still slow on my own server).

Comment: *"takes about 5 minutes to render a PDF of 23 sheets"*. Did you test the very same PDF with a few different PDF readers on a normal workstation (not browser/remote)? Sometimes even Acrobat Reader needs a looongish time to render a complex PDF. You can then see that the page in question builds up very slow on screen. So whatever library you test -- make sure you test with PDFs that behave 'normally'....

Comment: Do you know how much I'm going to reduce simplifying table structure with dompdf? I need a huge performance improvement,i.e at least an improvement of 90%  in order to render a PDF of 23 sheets in 30 seconds (more or less).

Comment: @alasarr as I said, even after reducing the complexity of the table it was still slow to render on my own system. It really depends on your server, though, so you may have better luck on your own system. Try out the version I linked to see if there's any improvement in rendering performance. Frankly, dompdf as it stands right now just requires a lot of resources to render such a large table.

Comment: If you want to stick with dompdf, the other option you can try is to break your table up some. Since the widths are specified you could limit the number of rows per table and start a new one after that. Let me know if you need to see a sample.

Comment: @BrianS with your example my server gives a segmentaion fault, I've to remove content (around 2 pages) ant it's takes 2 minutes 30 seconds in a i7 server with 8GB RAM.

Comment: @alasarr segfault, huh? Wouldn't expect that, though we have seen this on some versions of PHP. Which is installed on your server? Still, process is taking too long so you might try my other suggestion if you want to stick with dompdf.

Comment: @BrianS I'm using 5.3.10 but don't be worried by segfault, see my new answer

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) seems to be doing well.

It does not rely on PHP to do the heavy lifting, but instead it uses the webkit-engine to render the page.

The downside is that it has not been updated in a while.

Comment: Yes, you just forgot to mention it needs running X server running server-side and performance is awful.

Comment: performance awful? not sure at all! One of best pdf convertor library

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FPDF ?

FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

[FPDF : class which allows to generate PDF files](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en)

You can also use [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/) with FPDF. With FPDI you will be able to import single pages of existing PDF documents into templates.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test it and I'll post my results

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.fpdf.org/

I use it and its very good, flexible, you can set size of a page, you can also use template ([fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/) - works with fpdf). You can put images, text, set position of each element.

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmark results:

To renderer this file (with only plain divs) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15451865/notables_dompdf.html on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz, 8 GB RAM memory (Ubuntu 12.04):

Dompdf: 35 seconds with a CPU rate of 100%

Google Chrome PDF printer: 1 seconds

So I think DOMPDF is an amazing library but for a service which needs high performance I need another library (I'll try FPDF).

Comment: I html table with minimal content and 200 rows times 5 columns took almost 20 seconds to load. I realize this is an old answer, but did you have any luck with FPDF?